# How to manually call Backbone.js view's method

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, browser-extension

I'm writing a browser extension for a site that uses [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/). Its pertinent code looks like the following (names have been changed to protect the innocent):

```
var BigContainer = BigContainer || {};
(function($, exports) {
    var Thing = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...

    useful_func: function() {
        // Does something I need to call
    },
    ...
});

(function($, exports) {
    BigContainer.BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    ...
    render: function() {
        this.local_thing = new Thing({
            el: '.local_thing'
        });
    }
    ...
});
```

I am also inserting some code in a `<script>` block to listen for `postMessage()` calls I make from my extension's injected javascript file. I would like to be able to call `useful_func` from there, but can't figure out how, or if I'm even supposed to (and if not, then how I can arrive at the same result).

As an example, I've tried the following references, all of which show up as undefined:

- `BigContainer.BaseView.$local_thing`
- `BigContainer.BaseView.local_thing`
- `Thing`
- `document.getElementsByClassName('local_thing')[0].useful_func`

Importantly, since I'm writing an extension for a site I don't own, I can't modify the site's Backbone.js code to help myself out. I need to work with what's there.

Comment: Where are you creating the `BaseView` instance? You would have to do `inst.local_thing.useful_func` on that specific view instance.

Comment: I updated my code to add that. They're both wrapped in functions, so no instance reference is retained, from what I can tell.

Comment: So to be clear, you are defining the views in the code you have given, but somewhere you do `var view = new BaseView(); view.render();`, to actually create a new isntance, so use that `view` with my previous snippet.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, Thanks for the help. I'm trying to read through the code and find what you're describing (it weighs in over 5600 lines of code).

Comment: Based on the name, it is also possible your code is doing `BaseView.extend`, in which case it will be the child views that are being `new`ed.

Comment: I was able to track it down by searching for "new " and I did manage to grab a reference. Thanks a million! I'll provide a summary answer when I can.

Comment: Cool. If you put that snippet in your question, I can put an official answer so this doesn't sit unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the line `BigContainer.BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({`, you are defining a new View type called `BaseView`, but it is only the definition. What you need is the actual instance of the view in your code. That would be somewhere where you do `new BaseView` (in this case, it's the following:)

```
// Where view is created
(function($, undefined) {
    BigContainer.OtherThing = {
    ...
    create: function(config, params) {
        this.view = new BigContainer.BaseView(...);
    }
    ...
})
```

With that found, you would do something like this:

```
// Your code, reach into that instance and its subview, and call 'usefulFunc'.
BigContainer.OtherThing.view.local_thing.useful_func();
```